# Shortcode generated widget to appear on same line as heading text and button

Tags: plugins, shortcode, widgets

I've been struggling with this one for a while now, with very little CSS or HTML skill.

As you can see on my staging site, (http://staging.kempen-design.com/ewc) I have a top notification bar, where I am displaying a countdown shortcode plugin with some text and a button wrapped around it.

The problem is, I would like the elements to display on the same line, instead, they are appearing individually, stacked in 3 rows.

Here is what I have appearing within the top notification bar content field.

```
<div> Global Temperatures to increase 1.5 degrees celcius by 2030 [widget id="shailan-countdown-widget-4" widget]</div>
```

What is the path of least resistance here? And would it be better for me to contact the plugin authors directly about this?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see a notification bar with a countdown anywhere?

Comment: Its there, just let the site load, it should appear at the very top of the site